# Spaces in Java file path to an executable

Tags: java

Ok, I know this is probably a noobish question, but I'm pretty new to Java, and it'll probably be fairly easy to answer. What I'm trying to do is make a program that will use a file path to open Firefox, but it seems there is a problem with the file path. I did some research and used the double slash to nullify the escape characters, but it still doesn't work. I think it has to do with the fact that there spaces in some of the directories' names. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Automation {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    }
}
```

I know its pretty simple, but I can't still figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla firefox\\firefox.exe\"");
```

... or with Java 7 against Windows ...

```
String[] command = new String[] {
    "C:" +
    File.separator + 
    "Program Files (x86)" +
    File.separator + 
    "Mozilla firefox" + 
    File.separator + 
    "firefox.exe"    
};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: When I do this, it says "Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments" Not sure what that means.

Comment: @LakshithaRanasingha after a double-check, it doesn't seem to work with all Java versions. Namely, it might fail in Java 7. Try this post for more alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243993/how-to-execute-command-line-exe-file-in-java

Comment: @Mena - please update your answer with those findings, because that might help other readers.

Comment: Ok I've edited my post. Note that I'm neither on Windows nor on Java 7 so I can't _prove_ it works :( Feeling a bit lame now...

Answer (score 1):

```
"\"C:\\ .......\""
```

So you can "escape" the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution for your problem should be like this.

```
String [] cmds = new String [1];
cmds[0] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla firefox\\firefox.exe";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

This is because `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` actually doesn't execute the program as command line interpreter does.  So you need to use a parameter array when you have white spaces in the path. you can provide extra flags/options in this array (ex: open).

This is some extra information. As far as I know Windows is perfectly happy with forward slashes (`/`), because Windows API accepts forward and backward slashes (starting from `MS DOS 2.0` i think). for example you can do `dir "c:/Program Files (x86)"` will work fine give you the directory list. Furthermore, without white spaces `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/SomeProgram/someprogram.exe");` works fine . However the recommended way is to get the file separator from the environment. That's using `File.separator`

Comment: This is not a totally correct answer. You have to use " around the cmd string, like in my answer above.

Comment: Really ? have you run this ? my JVM doesn't tell it. there's no need of escaping as you told. this is real code which executes in java 6 & 7.